# Is there any random.choices() function in Python Processing

Tags: python, processing

Does anybody know if there is any equivalent to

```
import random
random.choices(population, weitghts, k=1)
```

.. for [Python Mode for Processing](https://py.processing.org)?.

I want to deploy an algorithm for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127467/how-to-re-order-units-based-on-their-degree-of-desirable-neighborhood-in-proc) StackOverflow question, but can't find the desired function.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is really Python at all. [The reference on mentions a few trivial randomness related APIs, with minimal Python overlap](https://py.processing.org/reference/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python mode for Processing [is built on Jython, and Jython still hasn't crawled out of the Python 2 era](https://py.processing.org/tutorials/python-jython-java/) (it only moved to Python 2.7 compatibility, from 2.5, in 2015, half a decade after 2.7 released).

[`random.choices` was introduced in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices); even if Python mode for Processing offered full access to all Python features (and I have a hard time determining if it does), Jython's 2.7 compatibility means it has almost no features introduced after Python 3.1, so `random.choices` is not available without reimplementing it from scratch. Of course, the code for `random.choices` [is open source and posted online](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0eaf7b975bd61169a8d78945d2d12f23299f61a8/Lib/random.py#L344), so you could always just backport it to Python 2 yourself (along with `itertools.accumulate`, which it relies on).